# WebCachedImageView error parsing XML when inflating view

Tags: java, android, xml, imageview

I'm using the WebCachedImageView from https://github.com/leocadiotine/WebCachedImageView

I think I did the link between the projects correctly, the JAVA files can recognize the WebCachedImageView class and it compiles without any problem but the XML parts can't

The WebCachedImageView element is in a layout cell for a listview that have an Array Adapter for it, I'm getting this error:

```
>FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #31: Error inflating class android.view.WebCachedImageView
>at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
>at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:643)
>at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
>at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
>at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
>at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
>at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
>at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
>at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
>at br.com.geen.istunning.view.ShoppingArrayAdapter.getView(ShoppingArrayAdapter.java:41)
```

The array adapter (part):

```
import android.view.WebCachedImageView;

public class ShoppingArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Shopping> {

private final Context context;
private final Shopping[] values;

public ShoppingArrayAdapter(Context context, Shopping[] values) {
    super(context, R.id.mainListView, values);
    this.context = context;
    this.values = values;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Shopping spc = values[position];

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    //line 41 below, the one that points to the error in the stack trace
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cell_listview, parent, false);
    //Compiles ok! Import ok!
    WebCachedImageView icon = (WebCachedImageView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.icon);

    TextView nomePeca = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.titleList);
    TextView nomeVendedora = (TextView) rowView
            .findViewById(R.id.descriptionList);
    TextView valor = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.valueList);
    nomePeca.setText(spc.getNome());
    nomeVendedora.setText(spc.getNome_dona());
    valor.setText("R$ " + spc.getValor_para_venda());
    icon.setImageUrl(spc.getUrl_imagem());
    //setImages(spc.getUrl_imagem(), rowView);

    return rowView;
}
```

The XML have:

```
    <WebCachedImageView android:id="@+id/icon" />
```

but eclipse don't have autocomplete nor recognizes the custom "app:" namespace, currently not in the XML but won't change if I put it.

Any ideas? I suspect something in the linking/registering of the custom component.

Answer (score 1):

How did you link the projects? Did you add WebCachedImageView as an Android Library Project?

Comment: http://www.tatirandotruta.net/share/tmp/Screenshot-1.png and http://www.tatirandotruta.net/share/tmp/Screenshot.png

Comment: Can you change
`<WebCachedImageView android:id="@+id/icon" />`
to
`<WebCachedImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />`
like it says in the docs? Android views require width and height.

Comment: It was like this before, just simplified to post, sorry, I tried the cache thing also with the given namespace but it won't recognize the namespace also.

Comment: Strange… Sorry, it seems that the only way I can help is if you send me your source code. Can you remove all the parts that are private and send me a sample, so I can try to fix the issue?